# crawl only picks up parent term set not the level2

Tags: crawling, taxonomy, term-store

Is it normal for crawl to pick up just the parent term set. For example, I have a parent term set called "Math" and i have bunch Terms under Math. (Math 101, Math 102, Trig 101, etc.).

An individual with Math tag is only being crawl. So when I do a search for Math 101 , he does not show up in the result. I even checked the crawl database and saw he is only listed for Math. Is it possible for crawl to populate all the child of Math for this guy?

Please suggest. I feel like SP has bunch of bugs or it's being overlooked during it's design.

Comment: stupid question, but did you tag your documents with the math 101 metadata, or didnt you?

Answer (score 1):

As Bas suggests, you have to have used (one of) the child terms. When you do, the search is working fine on these child terms.